# dtreeviz replace plot, regression too many points

Tags: python, matplotlib, decision-tree, dtreeviz

How can I replace the node-plots from dtreeviz by a custom plot function from me?

Alternatively: I want to replace the dtreeviz-plots with a 2d-histogram: y-axis=y-values, x-axis: values from the split feature, grid over the plot, each grid-cell gets the number of samples inside as color. (If that is already implemented in some package would also be great) In matplotlib the plotting function for that is called `hist2d()`

---

I use sklearn to learn a regression decision tree and visualize the results with dtreeviz.

MWE: (see https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz#regression-decision-tree)

```
from sklearn.datasets import *
from sklearn import tree
from dtreeviz.trees import *

regr = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=2)
boston = load_boston()
regr.fit(boston.data, boston.target)

viz = dtreeviz(regr,
               boston.data,
               boston.target,
               target_name='price',
               feature_names=boston.feature_names)
              
viz.view()
```

[image]

Now I do have millions of samples in my problem and the resulting `.svg` is extremely slow (read 'impossible') to display. I could only use that visualization using downsampling.

Example 2d histogram:

[image: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/scales/power_norm.html#sphx-glr-gallery-scales-power-norm-py]

(From https://matplotlib.org/gallery/scales/power_norm.html#sphx-glr-gallery-scales-power-norm-py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you would have to alter the software as it was not designed to have plug-and-play node figures. It was extremely difficult  to convince all of the tools in the chain to work together, even without allowing such flexibility.

Comment: No worries, I am already very happy with what works - I feared that it would be complicated. Great work though!

Comment: Thanks!  glad to be of service.